# How do I create a simple user form in SharePoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, office-365, custom-form, 2016

I want to create a simple user form in Sharepoint 2016 that has below details. When a user clicks submit, it should send mail to a group of people.

**USER REGISTRATION**

```
NAME:  
TITLE:  
REGION:  
email-id:  
Tentative dates:  
Comments:  

**Submit**
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Hello @MAHALAKSHMI G, Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 1):

No code, no workflow solution? You can create ordinary custom list or better Survey type list (Site Contents > add an app) with any custom fields (Ribbon menu List > Create column) or questions (Settings > add new Question) you want to have like Name, Title, Region, etc. Then create alert e-mail notification for every new item, that appears in a view.

The good thing is, read and edit rights there can be assigned to the user who create an item only (cannot read other's responses) and for the Survey you can allow or deny multiple responses if needed. Also branching logic with no code can be used there. For example if User A select region A, you can display different set of fields (questions) for him than for Region B. Both lists can export responses like report in Excel.

[image]

Alerts can be assigned to e-mail enabled AD group, per unique user or more users if you want to, like for any other SharePoint list. You can find them inside Ribbon menu for list itself (custom list) or inside Actions for Survey.

[image]

The form (for custom list as well as Survey) can be assigned to a link or button already inserted into a page, using NewForm.aspx page instead of default Allitems.aspx view:

```
https://portal/sc/site/survey/NewForm.aspx
```

...with appended text for return to page, from which user comes:

```
https://portal/sc/site/survey/NewForm.aspx?Source=https://portal/sc/site/home.aspx
```

So, user navigate to the page with instructions, click on the button, fill the form (respond to survey), submit the form and will be redirected automatically back to original page without unnecessary mouse-clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal through createing a `custom list` attached with a simple `workflow` that started on item created as the following:

## Steps:

**Create a custom list.**

- Site setting > Add and APP.

[image]

- Select custom list > provide its name.

[image]

- Add your columns with its data type as you prefer, by clicking on `Create a Column`.

[image]

See  [Create Custom List in SharePoint 2013](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1010356/Simple-Ways-to-Create-Custom-List-in-SharePoint)

**Create a notification email workflow.**

- Open Sharepoint Designer.
- Go to workflow, From the above ribbon, select List workflow > select you newly created list.
- From Actions> Select **Send An Email** action.

[image]

- Click on `Users` > and select WorkflowLokkup for User > select the list that contains the user and group field.

[image]

- In start option, Make sure to check `Start workflow on item created`.

[image]

- Publish your workflow.
- Test your workflow.